# Performing Actions after a loop

Tags: google-apps-script

GoogleAppScript working in GoogleSheets

Following code is working fine until I try to perform any action after the loop. It correctly logs the row which has "----CUT HERE----" as it's value. But after logging the row number I can not get it to perform next task. What am I missing?

```js
function FORMATKPIREPORT() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
  if (values[i][j] == "----CUT HERE----") {
  var cuthere = i+1;Logger.log(cuthere);return i+1;
  }
  }
  }

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastrow);

}
```

Now that I know what the CutHere row is I want to find the LastRow.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not able to getting anything past the `"--------Cut here--------"` is you terminate the code after that line using a `return` statement

So in the following line :

```
var cuthere = i+1;Logger.log(cuthere);return i+1;
```

return terminates the code, use break instead to exit the loop.

```
function FORMATKPIREPORT() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
  if (values[i][j] == "----CUT HERE----") {
  var cuthere = i+1;Logger.log(cuthere);break;
  }
  }
  }

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastrow);

}
```

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks for clarifying!